# In the proof of the Stokes's theorem, why $\varphi |_{U \cap \partial M}^{\varphi(U)\cap \partial \mathbb{H}^n}$ is an orientation-preserving?

Tags: differential-geometry, orientation

I am reading John Lee's Introduction to smooth manifold, second edition, proof of Theorem 16.11 and stuck at understanding some statement.

> Theorem 16.11 (Stokes's Theorem). Let $M$ be an oriented smooth $n$-manifold with boundary, and let $w$ be a compactly supported smooth $(n-1)$-form on $M$. Then
> $$\int_Mdw=\int_{\partial M}w.$$

We accept this theorem for $M=\mathbb{H}^n$, the upper half-space. In fifth paragraph of the proof, he argues as follows :

Now let $M$ be an arbitrary smooth manifold with boundary, but consider an $(n-1)$-form $w$ that is compactly supported in the domain of a single positively or negatively oriented smooth chart $(U,\varphi)$. Assuming that $\varphi$ is a positively oriented boundary chart, the definition yeilds

$$ \int_Mdw := \int_{\mathbb{H}^{n}}(\varphi^{-1})^{*}dw = \int_{\mathbb{H}^{n}}d((\varphi^{-1})^{*}w) = \int_{\partial\mathbb{H}^{n}}(\varphi^{-1})^{*}w,$$

where $\partial\mathbb{H}^{n}$ is given the induced orientation. Since $d\varphi$ takes outward-pointing vectors on $\partial M$ to outward-pointing vectors on $\mathbb{H}^{n}$ ( by Proposition 5.41 ), it follows that **$\varphi |_{U\cap \partial M}$ is an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism onto $\varphi(U) \cap \partial \mathbb{H}^{n}$**, and thus

$$\int_{\partial\mathbb{H}^{n}}(\varphi^{-1})^{*}w = \int_{\varphi(U) \cap \partial \mathbb{H}^{n}}(\varphi^{-1})^{*}w = \int_{U \cap \partial M}w = \int_{\partial M} w.$$

**Q.** And why the bold statement ( $\varphi |_{U \cap \partial M}^{\varphi(U)\cap \partial \mathbb{H}^n}$ is orientation preserving ) is true? Intuitively it seems true, but I can't make a formal proof.

Here, the defintion of 'orientation-preserving' map is as follows :

> Definition. A local diffeomorphism $F: M \to N$ between oriented smooth manifolds with or without boundary of positive dimension is ***orientation-preserving*** if for each $p\in M$, the isomorphism $dF_p$ takes oriented bases of $T_pM$ to oriented bases of $T_{F(p)}N$.

Can anyone helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the piece you're missing is the definition of the induced orientation on the boundary $\partial M$. This definition is buried in Propositions 15.21 and 15.24, and can be summarised as follows:

> Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional manifold with boundary. Let $p$ be a point in $\partial M$, and let $N \in T_p(M)$ be an outward-pointing vector. We say that $(E_1, \dots, E_{n-1})$ is a positively oriented basis for $T_p(\partial M)$ if and only if $(N, E_1, \dots, E_{n-1})$ is a positively oriented basis for $T_pM$. This criterion is independent of our choice of $N$.

Now let's answer your question. We want to show that $\varphi|_{U \cap \partial M} : U \cap \partial M \to \varphi(U) \cap \partial \mathbb H^n$ is orientation preserving. This amounts to showing that $(d\varphi)_p$ maps a positively oriented basis of $T_p(\partial M)$ to a positively oriented basis of $T_{\varphi(p)}(\partial \mathbb H^n)$, for any $p \in U \cap \partial M$

So pick a $p \in U \cap \partial M$. Suppose $(E_1, \dots, E_{n-1})$ is a positively oriented basis for $T_p(\partial M)$. This means that for some outward-pointing vector $N \in T_p(M)$, $(N, E_1, \dots, E_{n-1})$ is a positively oriented basis for $T_p(M)$. (In fact, $(N, E_1, \dots, E_{n-1})$ is a positively oriented basis *for all* outward-pointing vectors $N \in T_p(M)$.)

Since $\varphi$ is a positively-oriented chart, the diffeomorphism $\varphi : U \to \varphi(U)$ is orientation preserving. So $((d\varphi)_p(N), (d\varphi)_p(E_1), \dots, (d\varphi)_p(E_{n-1}))$ is a positively-oriented basis for $T_{\varphi(p)}(\mathbb H^n)$.

$(d\varphi)_p(N)$ is an outward pointing vector in $T_{\varphi(p)}(\mathbb H^n)$, since $N$ is by assumption an outward pointing vector in $T_p(U)$. (The property of being an outward-pointing vector is preserved under pushforward by a diffeomorphism.)

So $((d\varphi)_p(E_1), \dots, (d\varphi)_p(E_{n-1}))$ is a positively oriented basis for $T_{\varphi(p)}(\partial \mathbb H^n)$, as required.

---

**Edit:** By the way, if it was me writing this proof, I would explain it differently. I even wrote notes for myself on this section of Lee to help me understand the accountancy of the plus and minus signs in my own way.

Let $(U, \varphi)$ be a boundary chart on $M$. Consider a  $(n-1)$-form of the form $$ \omega := g(x^1, \dots, x^{n}) dx^1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx^{n-1},$$
where $g(x^1, \dots, x^{n})$ is a smooth function compactly supported within $U$, and where $x^1 \dots x^n$ are the local coordinates associated with the chart $(U, \varphi)$.

[There are other $(n-1)$-forms to consider, but those are less interesting from the perspective of fixing plus or minus signs because they integrate to zero on both sides of the Stoke's theorem.]

Taking the exterior derivative of $\omega$, we get
$$ d\omega = (-1)^{n-1} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^n}(x^1, \dots, x^{n}) dx^1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx^{n-1} \wedge dx^n. $$

Integrating this on $M$, we get
$$ \int_M d \omega = \begin{cases} + (-1)^{n-1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx^1 \dots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\infty} dx^n \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^n} (x^1, \dots, x^{n}) & \text{if }\varphi \text{ positive oriented} \\ - (-1)^{n-1}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx^1 \dots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\infty} dx^n \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^n} (x^1, \dots, x^{n}) & \text{if }\varphi \text{ negatively oriented} \end{cases}$$

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, this simplifies to
$$ \int_M d \omega = \begin{cases} + (-1)^{n} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx^1 \dots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx^{n-1} g(x^1, \dots, x^{n-1}, 0) & \text{if }\varphi \text{ positive oriented} \\ - (-1)^{n}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx^1 \dots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx^{n-1}  g (x^1, \dots, x^{n-1}, 0) & \text{if }\varphi \text{ negatively oriented} \end{cases}$$

The chart $(U, \varphi)$ on $M$ naturally induces a chart $(U \cap \partial M, \varphi|_{U \cap \partial M})$ on $\partial M$. The local coordinates associated with the chart $(U \cap \partial M, \varphi|_{U \cap \partial M})$ are $x^1, \dots x^{n-1}$, i.e. they are the first $n-1$ of the local coordinates associated with the chart $(U, \varphi)$. Relative to these two charts, the inclusion map $\iota: \partial M\to M$ is given by $(x^1,\dots, x^{n-1})\mapsto(x^1,\dots,x^{n-1},0)$

We have
$$ \int_{\partial M} \iota^\star \omega = \begin{cases} +  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx^1 \dots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx^{n-1} g(x^1, \dots, x^{n-1}, 0) & \text{if }\varphi|_{U \cap \partial M} \text{ positive oriented} \\ -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx^1 \dots \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx^{n-1} g(x^1, \dots, x^{n-1}, 0) & \text{if }\varphi|_{U \cap \partial M} \text{ negatively oriented} \end{cases} $$

All that remains is to relate the orientation of $\varphi|_{U \cap \partial M}$ to the orientation of $\varphi$.

- If $n$ is even, then $\varphi|_{U \cap \partial M}$ is positively oriented (resp. negatively oriented) iff $\varphi$ is positively oriented (resp. negatively oriented).
- If $n$ is odd, then $\varphi|_{U \cap \partial M}$ is negatively oriented (resp. positively oriented) iff $\varphi$ is positively oriented (resp. negatively oriented).

You can easily verify my claim using Lee's definition of the orientation on $\partial M$. I suggest working with the basis $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{n-1}})$ for $T_p(\partial M)$, using $N = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n} \in T_p(M)$ as the outward pointing vector. Or check my claim against your multivariable calculus intuition in low dimensions.

Comparing our expressions for $\int_M d \omega$ and $\int_{\partial M} \iota^\star \omega$, we see that
$$ \int_M d \omega = + \int_{\partial M} \iota^\star \omega,$$
regardless of whether the original chart $(U, \varphi)$ is positively or negatively oriented, and regardless of whether $n$ is odd or even.

Comment: Wow, I got it. Thanks!

Comment: Uhm.. Can I ask further?  In the john lee's book p.381, he defined that "a smooth coordinate chart $\varphi$ on an oriented smooth manifold with or without boundary is 'positively oriented' if the coordinate frame $(\partial / \partial x^{i})$ is positively oriented." And how can we deduce that "$\varphi : U \to \varphi(U)$ is orientation-preserving" from this??

Comment: To answer your question, $d\varphi$ maps the basis $(\partial / \partial x^i)$ for $T_p(M)$ to the basis $(\partial / \partial x^i)$ for $T_p(\mathbb R^n)$. I've used the same notation for both bases, but one is a basis for $T_p(M)$ and the other is a basis for $T_p(\mathbb R^n)$. The second basis (the one on $T_p(\mathbb R^n)$) is obviously positively oriented, because that's just how the standard orientation on $\mathbb R^n$ is defined. Therefore, $\varphi$ is orientation-preserving iff the first basis (the one on $T_p(M)$) is positively oriented too!

Comment: On a different note, I've edited my answer, sharing my own notes on Lee's proof of Stoke's theorem. Maybe I'm weird, but I found Lee's explanation of the signs and orientations quite confusing, and I understood the proof better when I explained it to myself in my own way.

Comment: Thanks. To show the orientation preservation of $\varphi$, it is enough to check for 'one' oriented basis?

Comment: @Plantation That's right. Think about determinants...

Comment: Aha! O.K. Thanks. And I'll also review your helpful and fancy Edit. Thank you.

Comment: @Plantation is there a reason you didn't upvote this answer? It seems kind of odd to accept an answer ("this answer solved my problem" from the tooltip text) but not upvote it ("this answer is useful" from the tooltip text). Did the answer resolve your question without being useful?

Comment: @KennyWong I just realized that I misclicked on downvote, and I cannot correct this without any significant edit on the answer, or a moderator's action. I am sorry about this, I wanted to upvote this great answer.

Comment: @Didier, no worries, thanks for the kind words!